# Approach for extracting relevant text using Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: text-processing, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

**Context:**
I have a set of documents in SharePoint. I have set up Azure Cognitive Search (Standard tier) with data sources (SharePoint), index and indexers.  I have also added a semantic configuration.

**Outcome:**
Ask a question, and have the search find and return relevant sections from the documents.  I will use these sections to feed into OpenAI to construct a cohesive result.

I would like to replicate this Microsoft demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3t3qZu1Dy1k&t=572s It seems to me to create this 'demo' each document content is very small and they could easily be combined to pass into OpenAI.

**My experience so far:**
The results return the documents and rank them, which seems OK - however it returns a short 'caption' and the full text.  The caption is not necessarily related to my question - and can therefore not be used for the next step.  The full document is far too big to be used in OpenAI.

I have managed to get Semantic answers - however the question has to be so precise to get a result, and the associated text is limited.

**What I would like:**
I would like the search to return sub-sections of the document, where the results of my question may be.  If that is not supported, I feel I need an entirely new approach.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "I will use these sections to feed into OpenAI to construct a cohesive result" and "The full document is far too big to be used in OpenAI"? What is OpenAI in this context? P.S. [tag:openai] is for questions about the Open AI API (see the tag wiki for further details).

Comment: Happy that you removed the OpenAI tag. Was included to see if there are alternative approaches. The comment adds context and refers to the token limits. Hope this is ok.

Comment: I suspect the answer may be to do something like this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textsplit

Answer (score 0):

The demo you refer to works by feeding documents to Azure Cognitive Search. A query is then formulated as a question that uses the Semantic Search functionality to return a set of potential semantic answers extracted from the content in the index.

These potential semantic answers are then fed as a prompt to OpenAI's text completion service: https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/completion

[image: Screenshot from demo on YouTube]

First, you must ensure you can get good semantic answers. Inspect the content you have indexed and verify that it contains content that could semantically be an answer to the questions you test with. Good content should have declarations of facts. I.e., statements that could be used verbatim as an answer to a question. Examples:

- The capital of France is Paris.
- Forecast for 2022 is expected to be 22%.

The semantic functionality in Azure Search will only respond with a text section containing a potential answer to your question. If you can't get this step to work, you have to work on improving that. Either via semantic configuration, choice of content, or by making sure you process your content so that the items in your index contain the relevant content in the correct properties.

1. Ensure your content is indexed and mapped to properties in a sensible way
2. Work with the semantic configuration until you get sensible results
3. Once the previous two steps are ok, submit to OpenAI

I have tested the semantic text on two different data sets. Both were a combination of website content, PDF- and Word documents, etc. The topic and volume of content were essentially the same. From one data set, I could get excellent semantic answers. But, the other data set was disappointing.

My conclusion was that the content in the good data set was formulated and structured in a way that fits a semantic scenario. The other data set would often have logic and meaning presented in tables and layouts. As a human reading the content on paper, you would understand it. But, semantically, it would not make as much sense.

Comment: From what I can tell from the screenshot in that code- he is using the document contents not the answer. Also- just passing the short answer (that only sometimes comes back) to OpenAI feels like an approach that does not leverage the large language model to its max.

Comment: The document contents are the answers because the query type in Azure Search is Semantic. The responses you get are excerpts from your content that semantically are the best answer to your question from your content. Azure Search will only provide semantic results with verbatim (exact) text as it is written in your original content. 

It would not be relevant to submit full documents to OpenAI. And it would be prohibitively costly to do so. Grabbing all the semantic answer candidates from Azure Search and then using the "crossdoc" feature in OpenAI is pretty clever.

Comment: Your problem is that your documents are large. By using Azure Search in Semantic mode, you solve that by creating small versions of documents that only include the bits relevant to your question. Then you submit all of those small documents to OpenAI and ask for a crossdoc summary using the miniature documents and the question as input.  This will produce an answer which is a summary with original wording.